# Why do I see "cannot find symbol" when I compile this class?

Tags: java

I have a class with four constructors. When I try to compile the main class, I get the error "cannot find symbol" at the last line of this code fragment. But every constructor for this class defines `value`, so I don't know what's going on. What am I missing?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class PowerTwo {

    public PowerTwo(int n){
        final BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(n);
    }

    public PowerTwo(long n){
        final BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(n);
    }

    public PowerTwo(BigDecimal n){
        final BigDecimal value = n;
    }

    public PowerTwo(String n){
        final BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(n);
    }

    public int power(){
        BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2");
        BigDecimal remainder = value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make it a field, not a local variable:

```
public class PowerTwo {

private final BigDecimal value;
```

It should be outside the constructors.

Comment: Thank you. I'd tried adding it outside the constructors, but hadn't had the realization that I needed to remove the declaration within the constructors when I did that.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a local variable in each constructor which is not in scope in the last constructor.  Make it a property of the class instead.